# Computed attributes cannot be set : org_id

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am learning how to use Terraform. My aim is to deploy an architecture on GCP so here's my `main.tf` so far :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.85.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "google" {
  credentials = file(var.credentials_file)
  region      = var.region
  zone        = var.zone
}

data "google_organization" "org" {
  domain                = var.organization.display_name
  org_id                = var.organization.id
  directory_customer_id = var.organization.directory_customer_id
}
resource "google_folder" "shared" {
  display_name = "Shared"
  parent       = google_organization.org_id
}

resource "google_folder" "ddm" {
  display_name = "Data and Digital Marketing"
  parent       = google_folder.shared.name
}

resource "google_folder" "dtl" {
  display_name = "DTL"
  parent       = google_folder.ddm.name
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/organization#org_id), `org_id` is within the **Attributes Reference**

But I get the following errors:

```
╷
│ Error: Computed attributes cannot be set
│
│   with data.google_organization.org,
│   on main.tf line 17, in data "google_organization" "org":
│   17:   org_id                = var.organization.id
│
│ Computed attributes cannot be set, but a value was set for "org_id".
╵
╷
│ Error: Computed attributes cannot be set
│
│   with data.google_organization.org,
│   on main.tf line 18, in data "google_organization" "org":
│   18:   directory_customer_id = var.organization.directory_customer_id
│
│ Computed attributes cannot be set, but a value was set for "directory_customer_id".
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on main.tf line 22, in resource "google_folder" "shared":
│   22:   parent       = google_organization.org_id
│
│ A managed resource "google_organization" "org_id" has not been declared in the root module.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you might be after **importing** an existing org id into Terraform? Are you trying to create a new org or have an existing org and want to make it in Terraform?

Comment: I have an existing org in terraform, but I'd like to outline it, and the hierarchy of folders within the main.tf

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki, to be honest I'm not sure I can do this with a service account. Maybe I need a "bootstrap" terraform that is applied via the super administrator account, which imports the organization and creates the folder structure. Separately, I'd have another one that creates projects and resources within the projects via a service account... what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

The organization is set as a `data` source, but in the previous code, it is used like a `resource` block.

What needs to be done to reference the organization is this :

```
data "google_organization" "org" {
  organization          = var.organization.id
}
```

`org_id` is an output, not an input. The only acceptable inputs are `organization` or`domain`; they are mutually exclusive.

And use its outputs like this :

```
resource "google_folder" "shared" {
  display_name = "Shared"
  parent       = data.google_organization.org.org_id
}
```

EDIT : This, although syntactically correct, it might not work because the account used must be organization administrator on the organization level. I do not recomment using the `google_organization` data sourcejust to fetch the ID and other info, I ended up writing those in a variable and just calling it this way :

```
resource "google_folder" "shared" {
  display_name = "Shared"
  parent       = "organizations/${var.organization.id}"
}
```